# не запускается Docker Desktop Installer

Tags: windows, docker, docker-compose

не запускается Docker Desktop Installer, уже перепробовал все несколько раз, и чистил реестр, и пытался запустить через Toolbox, но безуспешно. Когда я пытаюсь запустить Installer то он просто не запускается ничего не происходит

1. Windows 10 Pro
2. Build 19045

Comment: А когда не запускается, что нибудь заместо запуска происходит?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904406/docker-desktop-installer-does-not-start не помогло?

Comment: @Acinit есть небольшие подгрузки и все

Comment: @teran это я тоже пробовал не помогает